# Unable to change and return value in Fortran subroutine + notebook

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I have a simple `fortran` subroutine (just for testing `python-fortran` interface). It looks like this:

```
subroutine sum2(x,y,z)
 real(kind=8),intent(in)::x,y
 real(kind=8),intent(inout)::z
 z = x + y
 print *, "sum is ", z
end subroutine sum2
```

After compilation with `f2py` I go to python and do the following:

```
>>> import sum2
>>> x = 1.0
>>> y = 2.0
>>> z = 0.0
>>> sum2.sum2(x,y,z)
sum is 3
>>> z
0.0
```

So, even though `z` is specified as `inout`, its value is not changed by the function. I need to know why. Another question concerns `notebook`. If I import `sum2` there and run `sum2.sum2(x,y,z)` I do not even see a message `sum is ...`. So, the question is, if it is possible to call fortran subroutines in a notebook?

**EDIT**

There was a reasonable comment, that in my example I used an immutable data type. So, I decided to change it, but still I have the same issue. So, my new `fortran` subroutine looks like this:

```
subroutine arr(x)
    real(kind=8),dimension(1)::x
    x(1) = 2 ! new value
    print *, "x[0] = ", x(1)
end subroutine arr
```

Again, I compile it with `f2py` and go to python:

```
>>> import arr
>>> x = [1]
>>> arr.arr(x)
x[0] = 2.000000000
>>> x
[1]
```

So, even though I now use a mutable type of data, I still have the same problem - I can't pass around variables between `python` and `fortran` code (or it is better to say, that I have one way road).

Comment: Why is z `intent (inout)`?  In your example, it's only output... the reason it doesn't change is because python float are immutable.  A workaround would be to pass in a 1-element array and unpack it on the other side, but that would be pretty ugly.

Comment: How does the Fortran code look like?

Comment: @ Vladimir F. Please, have a look at my updated question. Thanks!

Comment: Probably, the way how you compile it and run it will also be necessary.

Comment: I compile it like `f2py -m arr -c arr.f90`. And as for `running`, I showed that - just arr.arr(x)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to interface correctly between between Fortran and Python, the C wrapper around Fortran needs numpy arrays.

According to the notes inside the getting started tutorial of f2py (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/getting-started.html#the-quick-way), you could best pass a numpy array with a compatible data type. For real(kind=8), this is np.float64.

For the sum2 subroutine the following code worked for me:

```
>>> import sum2
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x=np.array(1.0,dtype=np.float64)
>>> y=np.array(2.0,dtype=np.float64)
>>> z=np.array(0.0,dtype=np.float64)
>>> sum2.sum2(x,y,z)
 sum is    3.0000000000000000
>>> z
array(3.0)
>>>
```

Comment: Right, I didn't notice he used a regular list in the second trial.